# Is it a correct sentence? ('How' sentence)

Tags: relative-clauses

'Your back won't hurt if you sit how I sit.'
'You shouldn't treat him how you treat your friends.'

Both are correct grammatically?

Comment: I'd say they are both ungrammatical since "how" can't be used like that.

Comment: *How* is used idiomatically like that all the time. At the very least, it's informally fine.

Comment: I agree with @JasonBassford that this is a common colloquial form, and few would question it in casual conversation; another common way of saying it is "like how". Nonetheless, a better construction would be "treat him like you treat...".

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences would sound a lot better if you replaced "how" with "the way".

Comment: '~if you sit the way I sit.'   '~if you sit like the way I sit.'  both are grammatically correct?

Comment: @BenPark I'd say the "like" is unnecessary.